# How to use multiple ListView/GridView in same UI?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview, android-scrollview

I want to use multiple `ListView`/`GridView` within same User Interface; I don't want them to be expanded to their full length and placed under `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn about ListView, here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html). About your question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing) is the similar one! Your question might even be duplicate of this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that putting multiple `ListView`/`GridView` objects inside `ScrollView` is a good idea.

The biggest advantage of `ListView`/`GridView` is that they reuse `View`'s. When you scroll a `ListView` what the system really does is to use fixed number of views, and swaps the view settings (text, image source etc.). This is done by requesting the `getView(int,View,ViewGroup)` method from the list `Adapter`.

What you are trying to do is to force the `ListView`/`GridView` to render all it's raws, which pretty much beats the whole purpose of using `ListView`/`GridView` in the first place.

Use `LinearLayout` inside the `ScrollView` instead, and then add `Views` dynamically from your `Activity`/`Fragment`

Comment: I am not trying to use `ListView/GridView` inside `ScrollView` please read my question first.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify dimensions to your `ListView`/`GridView` that are not all `match_parent`.

Also, if you want to proportionally allocate say 50% and 50% of available height to your list and grid, put them in a `LinearLayout` and use the `layout_weight` mechanism:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0px"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         ... />

    <GridView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="0px"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the layout to include how many listViews and gridViews as you wish. just choose a layout and set their sizes yourself. if you put them in a linearLayout, you can set a weight for each of them, to make their width/height proportional to the layout width/height.

However, do note that the more you put, the more cluttered the UI is.

Also note that Google suggests to never put listViews and gridViews inside ScrollViews (this was being talked about on the "the world of listView" lecture) .